# Github oauth apache2 django daphne python-social-auth | Authentication failed ... redirect_uri

Tags: django, apache, proxy

I can't get the oauth running on the productive server while there is no problem when testing with localhost:8000 during development.

This is the setup:
Apache as reverse proxy -> Daphne -> Django

This is the exception as answer when clicking on the oauth button to login:

```
AuthFailed at /oauth/complete/github/

Authentication failed: The redirect_uri MUST match the registered callback URL for this application.

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://nomoney.shop/oauth/complete/github/?error=redirect_uri_mismatch&error_description=The+redirect_uri+MUST+match+the+registered+callback+URL+for+this+application.&error_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.github.com%2Fapps%2Fmanaging-oauth-apps%2Ftroubleshooting-authorization-request-errors%2F%23redirect-uri-mismatch&state=bHGqHRlbQjIYNKJWrb8t46ia1XV5OuxM
Django Version:     3.0.5
Exception Type:     AuthFailed
Exception Value:    

Authentication failed: The redirect_uri MUST match the registered callback URL for this application.
```

Apache Proxy settings:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ...
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8002/
    ProxyPassReverse / https://127.0.0.1:8002/
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests Off
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

I think, the proxy setting causes that error but after hours of searching i cant find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

With a little luck i found the solution short after creating this question (it's the same problem, when using Gunicorn instead of Daphne:

---

I added this to the apache vhost

```
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto 'https' env=HTTPS
```

and added this to django settings.py

```
USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST = True
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
```

More informations:
https://ubuntu.com/blog/django-behind-a-proxy-fixing-absolute-urls